# Do not execute method if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi controller dedicated for WebJobs at Azure. I want to disable executing methods for concrete environment. 
I have idea to add appSetting to config file and if it's false then do not exectue these methods..

It's simple if I add this condition to methods. But I don't want do it. 
I was thinking about use CustomActionFilter and then if condition is meet return and do not execute method body. 
It is possible to do?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJobsShouldWork"] ?? "true"))
        // stop executing method
    else
        // go ahead
}
```

Comment: In web api it is `HttpActionContext` and not `ActionExecutingContext`

Comment: Yeah, thx. That why filter doesn't executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web api action filter you can create response and put it in `Response` of action context:

```
class SampleFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        if (/* some condition */)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            // go ahead
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();`

example:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJobsShouldWork"] ?? "true"))
        filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: This filter doesn't execute for HttpPost method.